# Missing Dialogflow Integrations Service Account after making Agent

Tags: dialogflow-es, service-accounts, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm not able to find the Service Account that usually shows up under the Project ID in this screenshot. I see online when people create an agent, they have a service account (already created) that is linked under the Project ID. Once Clicked, the Service Account will show it is of Dialogflow Integrations and you can make a key. How come I do not have a Service Account already made and how do I get a Dialogflow Integrations Service account like everyone else?

What I see:
[Dialogflow Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3uHc.png)

What others see when they make an agent:[Dialogflow with Service Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3xVu.png)

[Service Account for Dialogflow Integrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwEN0.png)

Comment: It seems that this screenshot with service account visible is quite old. I can see on the screenshot that you can choose Legacy V1 API there, while it is already depreciated and unavailable. I do not see service account in my console as well. Can you try ask "others" to provide fresh screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

I've read elsewhere that the integrations feature is only available for region US ("global") so I suggest you try making your agent on region "global".

This worked for me today.